# C# SOAP WSDL get results from Magento

Tags: c#, magento, soap, wsdl

I have SOAP wsdl from Magento and I have to get simple product list from it. 
Logic is to get 'simple' products from catalogProductList.

So far in VS2015 I have create console app, and in reference add service reference, paste url of wsdl, but further I have no idea what to do, also didn't find any similar examples.

In PHP code would be like this:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentowebshop/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 
$sessionId = $proxy->login('user', 'pass'); 

$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'simple')
        )
    )
);
$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $complexFilter);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: [This looks dated](http://www.csharptutorial.in/37/csharp-net-how-to-consume-a-web-service-in-csharp-net-visual-studio-2010), but so aren't SOAP services in general. Start at step 10, it is very similar to your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

When you added the serviceReference it asked you to input a NameSpace

[image: Add Web reference screenshot]

In your code use that namespace to create a client a be able to call the exposed methods of the WSDL

```
private void testMethod 
{
    ServiceReference1.ExampleClient client ;

    client = new ServiceReference1.ExampleClient();

    client.exampleMethod() ;

}
```

when you type `ServiceReference1.` you will see a list of the clients created based on the wsdl that you added.

and then when you type `client.` you will see methods that you can get to achieve what you want

Comment: ok, tnx. When I type client, I see method which I whant. I use for example catalogProductList which demand string of sessionid (which is user and apikey) then filter filter then string storeview, how to use last one, filter and store view?

Comment: sorry I can not help you with magento web shop, that is a different issue, check their suppport forums or here in SO, I believe the original question has been answered ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i find a solution:

```
    ServiceReference1.PortTypeClient client = new 
    ServiceReference1.PortTypeClient();

    string sessionID = client.login("user", "pass");

    filters filter = new filters();

    filter.complex_filter = new[]
    {
        new complexFilter
        {
            key = "type",
            value = new associativeEntity { key = "in", value = "simple"}
        }
    };
    var list = client.catalogProductList(sessionID, filter, "catalog");

    client.endSession(sessionID);
```